# How fast can a "heat front" propagate through a material?

Tags: thermodynamics, condensed-matter

Say I have some piece of material (geometry at least I don't think should matter) that is at a uniform temperature. It then is heated (say, by an incident laser beam or something) at one spot, with a uniform rate of heat input. From my understanding of heat conduction, from that moment on, the heat should spread out into the material, with the heated zone advancing steadily. Is there any simple way to calculate, from material properties, how fast the front of that heated zone should be moving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Emilio Pisanty's answer gives very valuable information, I feel it doesn't fully answer the title question. Hence my little addition. The heat equation he mentions has solutions that have an infinite speed of propagation, which is a characteristic of parabolic PDEs (which the common heat equation is). And clearly this is not the real speed at which heat propagates.

You mention a laser pointing onto a single material. If that material is a metal, then it is quite common to deal with more complicated PDE than the common heat equation, because the latter one is not a good approximation to describe the temperature anymore. A laser can induce an insane amount of heat in a very small region, causing temperature gradients so high that the temperature variations are of the order of $10^9  \mathrm{K}/ \mathrm{s}$. See this [reference](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2090997715000425) for instance.

The speed (as in units of distance divided by time) of heat propagation in a metal is roughly the Fermi velocity (i.e. about $10^6 \mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}$ for common metals), because that's the speed of the charge and dominant heat carriers (electrons). The case is very different for an insulator or a semiconductor, depending on the doping level. In an insulator the heat is propagated mostly thanks to phonons, whose speed are about 3 orders of magnitude lesser than the speed of electrons, so about $10^3 \mathrm{m}/ \mathrm{s}$. For semiconductors the speed of heat propagation should be roughly in between the one of insulators and metals.

I'll edit my answer later and add more information about heat propagation.

Edit: As promised, here is some information in line with Emilio Pisanty's answer (I think). If we take your case of a uniform temperature material as a 1D semi-infinite region and apply a laser pulse, the maximum temperature region is going to diffuse through the material in such a way that it is going to be attenuated with depth (exponentially) and time. The speed at which this maximum temperature region moves is not constant, it gets slower with time, again exponentially. You can easily visualize it if you play with for example [this online heat equation solver](https://math.uchicago.edu/~luis/pde/heat.html). I attach a few pictures showing these effects, at times $t=0$, $0.7$ and $1.3$ (almost twice $0.7$).

[image: t=0]

[image: t=0.7]

[image: [![t=1.3]]

Comment: Your estimate of $10^6\rm\,m/s$ for the "speed of heat" seems inconsistent with my experience of cooking this morning's breakfast in a cast-iron skillet: the base of the skillet got hot enough to cook my eggs while the handle was still cool enough for me to hold. I'm not suggesting your estimate is wrong, just that it may not mean quite what you intended.

Comment: My statements still hold. The variation of temperature might be extremely small, i.e. not even detectable with the best thermocouples, yet it still exists.

Comment: Also it seems you did not try to measure the actual speed (in m/s as I wrote in my answer) of heat. I think you confused a speed with a rate of change in temperature, which are completely different.

Comment: I'm not trying to suggest that you're incorrect, just that I don't understand you yet. I totally understand temperature flows in my skillet in terms of thermal conductivity, but I don't see how your "speed of heat" (which is a thousand times larger than the typical speed of sound in metals) is related.

Comment: Ah ok! What I mean is that if you heat a metal that is originally at a uniform temperature, say at point A, then the temperature of the surroundings is going to be affected at a speed of roughly the Fermi velocity, because the main heat carriers in metals are electrons that move roughly at those speeds. The common heat equation would predict an infinite speed of propagation, but this would violate relativity amongst other things. Is this clearer... or not?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is possible. The core dynamics of this are governed by the [heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation), which for your purposes takes in two key parameters:

- the rate of heat input, together with its distribution
- the [thermal diffusivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_diffusivity) of the material.

Generally speaking, heat doesn't really tend to form "fronts" with a sharply defined boundary. Instead, it acts much more like a diffusing pollutant, with a broad and smooth distribution that moves rather slowly (where 'slowly' means, specifically, that any given point in the distribution will often move with a time dependence of $\sqrt{t}$ instead of at a linear velocity).

The heat equation is a partial differential equation, so it's typically harder to solve than your garden-variety ODE, but as PDEs go it is one of the easiest to solve and one of the most stable to handle numerically. As such, it can be implemented quite easily in a numerical solver, and it can be handled via e.g. Fourier-transform methods, depending on what the geometry is.

Comment: Thanks - if I wanted to just roughly estimate how large the heated zone would be after a certain time, is there any really simple way to do it, or to maybe get a limit on how fast the heat can spread, no matter how high the temperature/heat input of the hot spot? Since I assume that after a finite time, the zone with a temperature different from the initial one will have to have a finite size too. This is in the sci-fi context of protecting against laser damage via thermal conductivity of the armour, so to estimate if you even can feasibly use that to protect against pulsed lasers.

Comment: @Zuthal This is likely very dependent on the particular geometry of your situation, and in particular on the positioning of heat sources and sinks. In addition, your assumption that "after a finite time, the zone with a temperature different from the initial one will have a finite size too" is actually incorrect; under the heat equation, a disturbance in the system will cause a (very tiny) difference in faraway areas instantaneously (though it is correct to say "after a finite time, the zone with a temperature difference _greater than some threshold_ will have a finite size").

Comment: @Zuthal That said, practically speaking this apparent violation of Special Relativity is rarely relevant (because, in practical terms, we only really care about _measurable_ temperature differences, which always involves some nonzero threshold, and because the speed of variations in the heat input to a system are usually pretty slow). It's just an interesting side note that is driving some current work in non-equilibrium thermodynamics at the moment.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, for a 1D uni-directional heat flow geometry, the effective penetration depth is on the order of $4\sqrt{\alpha t}$, where $\alpha$ is the thermal diffusivity.

Comment: @Zuthal That's a question for [worldbuilding.se], not here. If you're writing sci-fi, then estimating heat-diffusion rates seems completely misguided to me. If you do want anything concrete, though, then at the very least you need to specify what the geometry is, the heat diffusivity of the material, how much heat is in each pulse, and what the tolerances are. None of those will move your story along, and neither will the result.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Ah, I thought it would fit here since it concerns itself with the physics of the situation - and no, I am not looking for anything concrete, just a sort of rough estimate to be able to tell if realistic thermal conductivities could feasibly help.

Comment: @Zuthal Realistic thermal conductivities are of very little use (read: none) without 'realistic' thermal loads and tolerances.

Answer (score 0):

If we approximate the laser as a constant point source of heat (more formally, if we say that we have a delta-function heat source $P\delta(\vec{r})$ for laser power $P$), and if we approximate the armor as a 2D infinite sheet (i.e. if the armor is thin, so that the heat penetrates fully through the thickness of the armor and the temperature is constant as a function of depth), then the solution as a function of time and the distance $r$ from the laser is given by:

$$T(r,t)=\frac{P}{C_m\sigma}\frac{1}{4\alpha}\Gamma\left(0,\frac{r^2}{4\alpha t}\right)+T_0$$

where $C_m$ is the specific heat capacity (heat capacity per unit mass, in J/(kg K)) of the material, $\sigma$ is its density (in kg/m$^2$), $\alpha$ is the thermal diffusivity, and $T_0$ is the initial temperature of the material. The function $\Gamma$ is the *incomplete gamma function*, and is here equal to

$$\Gamma\left(0,\frac{r^2}{4\alpha t}\right)=\int_{\frac{r^2}{4\alpha t}}^\infty \frac{e^{-z}}{z}dz$$

Unfortunately, this function cannot be written any simpler using elementary functions. We can, however, plot this solution as a function of position and time:

[image]

Now suppose that you're interested in the radius $R$ which is hotter than $T_0$ by a specific amount $\Delta T$. This means solving the equation

$$\Delta T = \frac{P}{C_m\sigma}\frac{1}{4\alpha}\Gamma\left(0,\frac{R^2}{4\alpha t}\right)$$

This equation has a partially-analytical solution: using the dimensionless parameter $\eta = \frac{4C_m\sigma\alpha\Delta T}{P}$, we have that

$$R(t)=f(\eta)\sqrt{\alpha t}$$

Once again, there is no analytical expression (that I know of) for $f(\eta)$, but it can be plotted:

[image]

For large values of $\eta$ (corresponding to low laser power, high $\Delta T$, high thermal diffusivity, high density, and/or high specific heat), the following approximation appears to hold (I have no idea why this is true, but it works remarkably well asymptotically):

$$f(\eta)\approx \frac{\pi^4}{65}e^{-\frac{\eta}{2}}$$